# How to check if a variable (e.g. $3) exists so that I don't get a warning about "uninitialized value"?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to run a script on a .csv file that converts sizes in feet and inches to separate columns of width in inches and height in inches.

It works fine when not using strict mode, but returns a warning message when `use warnings;` is set.

My problem occurs here:

```
if ($data[$index_num] =~ /(\d+)'( (\d+)'')? x (\d+)'( (\d+)'')?/) {

    my $width = $1*12+$3;
    my $height = $4*12+$6;

    ...
}
```

Since sometimes the size could be 5' x 8' the special variables $3 and $6 do not exist.

All possible size formats are as follows:

1. 5' 1'' x 6' 7''   (All Single Digits)
2. 10' 1'' x 5' 10''  (Combination of Single and Double Digits)
3. 5' x 8'              (No Inches)
4. 4' 6'' x 7'  (Combination of No Inches and Inches)

The warning I receive is:

> Use of uninitialized value $6 in addition (+) at script.pl line 47,  line 567.

This is happening in either case 3 or 4 where the inches are missing on either the width or height.

How can I check to see if either $3 or $6 exists before trying to use them?

Comment: would http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html be an option?

Comment: Please note that the message about using an undefined variable is *not* an error. It is a warning. If your script "isn't working" with `use warnings` it will not work without warnings either.

Comment: @innaM, Thank you. I've edited my question and learned something as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `defined` function:

```
my $height;
if(defined($6))
{
    $height = $4*12+$6;
}
else
{
    $height = $4*12;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

First, let's get rid of useless captures:

```
/(\d+)'(?: (\d+)'')? x (\d+)'(?: (\d+)'')?/
```

Captures that didn't match are set to `undef`, so you can used `defined` or `//`.

```
my $width  = $1 * 12 + ($2 // 0);
my $height = $3 * 12 + ($4 // 0);
```

`//` was introduced in Perl 5.10. For backwards compatibility, you can use the following:

```
my $width  = $1 * 12 + ($2 || 0);
my $height = $3 * 12 + ($4 || 0);
```

The second version uses zero when `$2` (or `$4`) is false (undef, zero, or empty string) rather than undef, but that's perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to test for a number AND you're happy to calculate a result when there is no match then you could say:

```
if ($data[$index_num] =~ /(\d+)\'( (\d+)\'\')? x (\d+)\'( (\d+)\'\')?/) {

    my $width = ( $1 || 0 ) * 12 + ( $3 || 0 );
    my $height = ( $4 || 0 ) * 12 + ( $6 || 0 );

    ...
}
```

Why does this work? Because if, say, `$1` is undefined, then `($1 || 0)` returns the right-hand side, or `0`. Likewise if `$1` is zero then the left-hand-side of the OR condition will also fail but return `0` nonetheless. And if `$1` is non-zero and defined then the left-hand-side will be returned (`$1`).

If you're going to use the `||` technique then ensure you put the left-hand and right-hand sides inside parenthesis to avoid operator-precedence side effects.

Comment: `$1` can't be undefined. It's probably worth mentioning that `||` can also replace the value even if it is defined (though that's fine here).

Comment: @ikegami, how would the `||` replace the value?

Comment: It's covered in my answer.